# How to return QAndroidJniObject from a native function?

Tags: java, android, c++, qt, java-native-interface

I'm trying to return `QAndroidJniObject` from a native function. Using Qt 5.5 and QtAndroidExtras.
This is my first naive implementation:

```
QAndroidJniObject doSomething() {
  return QAndroidJniObject("android/os/Bundle", "()V");
}

static jobject nativeFunc(JNIEnv *env, jclass, jlong nativePointer, int, jstring, jstring, jstring)
{
  QAndroidJniObject obj = doSomething();                                       
  return obj.object();
}
```

Unfortunately, I'm getting an error:

```
I/dalvikvm(32413): JNI ERROR (app bug): accessed deleted global reference 0x1de00462
```

When `QAndroidJniObject` is destroyed, the underlying java object is also destroyed. It seems that `QAndroidJniObject` does not have a `detach()` method or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved this issue by creating a new [local reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#global_local):

```
return env->NewLocalRef(obj.object<jobject>());
```